# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController'

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data

I've started my project by creating entities, services and JUnit tests for services using Spring data. All of this works great. Then I've added spring-mvc to make this web application using many different step-by-step tutorials, but when I'm trying to make Controller with @Autowired annotation.
And I got an Exception from the Eclipse and I tried to solve it , but I still can't handle this problem.

**PersonRepsoitory**

```
package com.wei.springdata;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

//@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass=Person.class,idClass=Integer.class)
public interface PersonRepsoitory extends JpaRepository<Person,Integer> {
}
```

**PersonService_interface**

```
package com.wei.springdata;

import java.util.List;

public interface PersonService_interface {
   public void savePersons(List<Person> persons);
   public List<Person> getAllPerson();
}
```

**PersonService**

```
package com.wei.springdata;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class PersonService implements PersonService_interface{

@Autowired
private PersonRepsoitory personRepsoitory;

@Override
public void savePersons(List<Person> persons){
    personRepsoitory.save(persons);
}
@Override
public List<Person> getAllPerson() {
    List<Person> person=new ArrayList<Person>();
    Iterable<Person> personIterable=personRepsoitory.findAll();
    Iterator<Person> perosnIterator=personIterable.iterator();
    while(perosnIterator.hasNext())
    {
        person.add(perosnIterator.next());
    }
    return person;
   }


}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- 配置自動掃描的包 -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wei.springdata">
</context:component-scan>

<!-- 1. 配置數據源 -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>  
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"></property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.jdbcUrl}"></property>

    <!-- 配置其他属性 -->
</bean>

<!-- 2. 配置 JPA 的 EntityManagerFactory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 

class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"></bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.wei.springdata"></property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- 二级緩存相關 -->
            <!--  
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache-hibernate.xml</prop>
            -->
            <!-- 生成的數據表的列的映射策略 -->
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
            <!-- hibernate 基本属性 -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 3. 配置事務管理器 -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>    
</bean>

<!-- 4. 配置支持注解的事务 -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- 5. 配置 SpringData -->
<!-- 加入  jpa 的命名空间 -->
<!-- base-package: 掃描 Repository Bean 所在的 package -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.wei.springdata"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"></jpa:repositories>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<!-- 通知 spring-webmvc 掃描「某自訂套件」內，是否有被相關Annotation設定為元件的類別  -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.wei.springdata.controller." />
<!-- 必須使用以下標籤啟用「自訂控制器」內 @Controller 的Annotation支援 -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Internal Resource View (內部資源視圖): -->
<!-- 在Spring MVC中，對於好的做法，它總是建議把整個Views或JSP文件放在"WEB-INF"目錄底下， 以保護其免受透過手動輸入網址而直接存取(direct access)。 -->
<!-- 放在"WEB-INF"目錄底下的這些Views或JSP文件，被命名為Internal Resource View (內部資源視圖)， 因為它只能由透過servlet或Spring控制器類別來存取。 -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<!-- 靜態資源目錄resources，存放如 CSS/JavaScript...等 -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Spring3.1開始支援-方法級別驗證 (JSR-349 Bean Validation 1.1) -->
<bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor"/>
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.wei.springdata.PersonService com.wei.springdata.controller.PersonController.personService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.wei.springdata.PersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.wei.springdata.PersonService com.wei.springdata.controller.PersonController.personService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.wei.springdata.PersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:657)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:466)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.wei.springdata.PersonService com.wei.springdata.controller.PersonController.personService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.wei.springdata.PersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.wei.springdata.PersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 31 more
```

Comment: You need to autowire the interface, not the concrete class. And please, respect the Java naming conventions, and fix the speling of PersonRepsotory.

Comment: OK, I  already fixed and used your advice

Answer (score 0):

In You spring-servlet.xml the  tag looks wrong: The package name ends with a dot.
Try
    `<context:component-scan base-package="com.wei.springdata,com.wei.springdata.controller" />`

instead!